# Installing mysql 5.6 fails on VM + vagrant

Tags: mysql, virtualization, vagrant

Error

```
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.6
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
vagrant@:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a

Setting up mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.6
```

```
vagrant@:~$ sudo apt-get install -f

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.6
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ dpkg -S etc/mysql

mysql-common: /etc/mysql/my.cnf
mysql-server-5.6: /etc/mysql/debian-start
mysql-common-5.6, mysql-server-5.6, mysql-common: /etc/mysql/conf.d
mysql-server-5.6: /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf
mysql-common-5.6: /etc/mysql/conf.d/my5.6.cnf
mysql-common-5.6, mysql-server-5.6, mysql-common: /etc/mysql
```

I have done following as well

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

But no luck.

Tried

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-5.5 mysql-client-5.6 mysql-server-5.6 
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6 mysql-common mysql-client-5.6


Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libmysqlclient18 libterm-readkey-perl
  mysql-client-core-5.6 mysql-common-5.6 mysql-server-core-5.6
Suggested packages:
  libclone-perl libmldbm-perl libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl
  libsql-statement-perl mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libmysqlclient18 libterm-readkey-perl
  mysql-client-5.6 mysql-client-core-5.6 mysql-common mysql-common-5.6
  mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server-core-5.6
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 65 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/22.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 169 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package libaio1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 70985 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libaio1_0.3.109-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libaio1:amd64 (0.3.109-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.7.10-1ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.7.10-1ubuntu14.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmysqlclient18:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libmysqlclient18_5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmysqlclient18:amd64 (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdbi-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libdbi-perl_1.630-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdbi-perl (1.630-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdbd-mysql-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libdbd-mysql-perl_4.025-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdbd-mysql-perl (4.025-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libterm-readkey-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libterm-readkey-perl_2.31-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libterm-readkey-perl (2.31-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-core-5.6.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-core-5.6_5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-5.6.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-5.6_5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.6.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.6_5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Replaced by files in installed package mysql-common (5.7.10-1ubuntu14.04) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.7.10-1ubuntu14.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.6.
(Reading database ... 71365 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.6_5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Replaced by files in installed package mysql-common (5.7.10-1ubuntu14.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common-5.6.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common-5.6_5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up libaio1:amd64 (0.3.109-4) ...
Setting up libmysqlclient18:amd64 (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
Setting up libdbi-perl (1.630-1) ...
Setting up libdbd-mysql-perl (4.025-1) ...
Setting up libterm-readkey-perl (2.31-1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
mysql start/running, process 9975
Setting up mysql-common-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
```

It got installed but now "select version()' show 5.7
and

```
vagrant@:~$ apt-cache show mysql-server | grep Version
Version: 5.7.10-1ubuntu14.04
Version: 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2
Version: 5.5.35+dfsg-1ubuntu1
```

Why would i be seeing 5.5 !!! No idea whats wrong in here!

Please let me know how can I fix this issue.